# Update to tutorial, ROS/Tutorials/Recording and playing back data

Tags: simulation, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the Recording and playing back data tutorial (I wasn't allowed to post the link because of low karma) in the section "Recording a subset of the data" the old form of command velocity is used and I just thought there should be a note reminding new users to change to the new form of command velocity. I am specifically referring to the following command line: $rosbag record -O subset /turtle1/command_velocity /turtle1/pose
It should be noted that you can use cmd_vel instead of command_velocity.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/181943/update-to-tutorial,-ros/tutorials/recording-and-playing-back-data/) by [nbanyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/19003/nbanyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2014-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial page has been updated.

---

Originally posted by [nbanyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/19003/nbanyk/) with karma: 40 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0